# Use two lists to create different sentences

Tags: python, list

So I have two lists. Let's say one list contain the capitals of each state in the US, and the other list contains the state. Both list are obviously ordered in such a way that the first element (capital) in list1 corresponds to the first element of list2 (states).

When only using one list, as if I only need to change one thing in a sentence, I currently use the following code:

```
list = map(str.strip, list(open('list.txt', 'r')))
questions = ['What is the capital of the state %s' %(element) for element in list]

with open('questions.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write("\n".join(questions))
```

So in this example I only use one list (list.txt) with US states, and by running the code it spits out a .txt file (questions.txt) with numerous lines saying:

```
What is the capital of the state California?
```

And whatever the list.txt have of states.

Now, back to my question. As stated, sometimes I need to use two lists in a sentence (or whatever I'm doing), like:

```
(first element of list1) is the capital of the US state (first element from list2)
(second element of list1) is the capital of the US state (second element from list2)
(third element of list1) is the capital of the US state (thirdelement from list2)
```

and so on...

But I'm not sure how I modify my above code to include two lists instead of one.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
List1 example:

```
Sacramento
Austin
Phoenix
```

List2 example:

```
California
Texas
Arizona
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the lists and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name please.

Comment: Updated with example. And sorry, I will never do that again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip` to iterate over a pair of lists:

```
capitals = tuple(map(str.rstrip, open('capitals.txt')))
states = tuple(map(str.rstrip, open('states.txt')))
answers = ['The capital of {} is {}'.format(state, capital) 
           for state, capital in zip(states, capitals)]
```

I've made some simplifications to your code and switched to the newer, recommended way to format strings.  I also wrapped `map` with `tuple` since in Python 3 `map` returns an iterable rather than a list.

Comment: Will this work with Python 2.7 as well ? I was told to begin with that, so that's currently where I am :)

Comment: Yes, in Python 2.7 wrapping `map` with `tuple` will work as well, although it will be a bit slower since `tuple` has to convert the list created by `map` into a tuple.

Comment: You don't need that tuple wrapping, `zip` handles any iterables.

Comment: @PM2Ring: That's fair, but the OP might want to reuse `capitals` and `states` later.  I often do this wrapping as a form of defensive coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
questions = ['What is the capital of the state %s' %(list[x]) for x in range(50)]
```

Try this.